# Avro Schema for unstructured data with random names

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, schema, avro

I need to save nested data objects with unpredictable names in an Avro schema. For example:

```
 {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
        "randomName1": 0.23,
        ...
    }
}
```

Because [creating recursive maps is only possible with records](http://apache-avro.679487.n3.nabble.com/Map-with-another-map-inside-unpredictable-naming-tp4037098p4037102.html), but records must have a field name, I think I need to transform the object into something else.

I though about one of these three options:

**(1) Array of nested key/value pairs**

Example:

```
[
    {
        key: "foo",
        value: "bar"
    },
    {
        key: "baz",
        value: [
            {
                name: "randomName1",
                value; 0.23
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
]
```

**(2) Flat map with dot-syntaxed key/value pairs**

Example:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz.randomName1": 0.23,
    ...
}
```

**(3) Array of flattened key/value objects**

Example:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
    },
    {
        "name": "baz.randomName1",
        "value": 0.23
    },
    ...
]
```

All three approaches translate well to Avro, but I am unsure of the implications of either approach, for example when trying to query those values via KSQL.

Any hint towards potentials gotchas further down the road is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the flat version works. Avro wouldn't allow dots in the keys because when compiled to a Java class (or similar for .NET and Python), field names can only be alphanumeric.

Comment: Good point, thanks!

Comment: how do you plan query this if the schema could eventually change? what tool are you using for querying ?

Comment: The schema is primarily used for data exchange between micro-services, but might also be queried with custom KSQL statements.