# avro dynamic nested map - similar to jsonschema object

Tags: avro, jsonschema

In jsonschema you can define generic properties of objects like this:

```
{
  "description": "Records the raw request and response of an HTTP exchange for debugging purposes.",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "response_json": {
      "description": "The response body as an optional JSON structure.",
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$": { }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "required": [],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

This is basically saying that you can have any keys (via `patternProperties`) and values of any type `{ }`.

This is similar to an avro map, but I don't see how to do make a map have a nested map to accommodate these payloads.

```
{
  "response_json": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": {
      "nested": "qux"
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "response_json": {
    "moo": "cow",
    "fish": {
      "pseudotropheus": {"type": "zebra"}
    }
  }
}
```

With an avro map, you could do something like this, but I don't think this allows arbitrary levels of nesting. I would have t just keep hard coding, and unioning all the types?

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "response_json",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": [
          "string",
          {
            "type": "map",
            "values": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": "sample",
  "namespace": "foo",
  "type": "record"
}
```

prior questions that seem relevant but didn't fully answer it for me:

[Avro Schema for unstructured data with random names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028802/avro-schema-for-unstructured-data-with-random-names)
[Can Avro schema have unknown / dynamic field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71748170/can-avro-schema-have-unknown-dynamic-field-names)
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2993

I've tried a number of avro schema definitions, but nothing seems dynamic enough like jsonschema.

I'm hoping for an example, or confirmation that this isn't possible and that I have to know at least the shape.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a recursive map type, e.g.:

```json
{
    "namespace": "io.nson.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Map",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "entries",
            "type": { "type": "map", "values": "Map" }
        }
    ]
}
```